# $ f '(x) \le g '(x) $ for all $ x\lt 1$ and $ f '(x) \ge g'(x) $ for all $ x\gt 1$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be two differentiable functions s.t $ f '(x) \le g '(x) $ for all $ x\lt 1$ and $ f '(x) \ge g'(x) $ for all $ x\gt 1$ then

1. If $f(1) \ge g(1)$, then $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x$
2. If $f(1) \le g(1)$, then $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x$
3. $f(1) \le g(1)$
4. $f(1) \ge g(1)$

In this I am having difficulty in guessing fxn to counter options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify life, take $\phi(x) = f(x)-g(x)$.

You are given $\phi'(x) < 0 $ for $x <1$ and $\phi'(x) >0$ for $x >1$. In particular, $\phi$ is decreasing for $x<1$ and $\phi$ is increasing for $x>1$.

1. You are given $\phi(1) \ge 0$. Since $\phi$ is increasing for $x>1$, we have $\phi(x) > 0$ for $x>1$ and since $\phi$ is decreasing for $x<1$, we have
   $\phi(x) >0$ for $x <1$. Hence $\phi(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x$.
2. You are given $\phi(1) \le 0$. However, since $\phi$ is increasing for $x>1$,
   it is entirely possible that it could be $>0$ for some $x$. Take $\phi(x) = x-1$, for example. (To translate this back to $f,g$ choose $g(x) = 0 $ and let $f(x) = \phi(x)$.)
3. Nothing has been specified about the value of $\phi$ at $x=1$, that is, if $\phi$ satisfies the derivative conditions, then so does the function $x \mapsto \phi(x)+c$, where $c$ is a constant. Choose $c$ so that 3. is violated.
4. See 3.

Answer (score 1):

$(f-g)' \leq 0 \to (f-g)(x) \geq  (f-g)(1) \geq 0$ for $x < 1$ and $(f-g)(x) \geq (f-g)(1) \geq 0$ for $x > 1$. Thus: $1)$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=(x-1)^{2}$ and $g(x)=(x-1)$. Then $f'(x)=2(x-1)$ and $g'(x)=1$. This clearly satisfies the constraint $f '(x) \ge g'(x)$ for all $x>1$ and $f '(x) \le g'(x)$ for all $x<1$. $f(1)=0$ and $g(1)=0$, but for any value of $x , f (x) > g(x)$. So option (1)